# Loop or function in r to create a new dataframe's column

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I have a dataframe with column A and B containing numeric values from 1 to 10.

```
    A B
1   5 9
2   7 2
3   2 1
4   1 9
```

I have add to the dataframe a new column OCCU with in each row the value
HOPD if one of the following two conditions hold: 3<A<9 or 3<B<9.
Otherwise the value to assign is LOPD.
For example in the above case, individual 1, and 2 have OCCU = HOPD, while 3, and 4 have OCCU = LOPD

Comment: Lucky you, now you have two answers, one with base R and one with tidyverse.

Comment: By the way, is not necessary to use a for loop, since in R data is vectorized.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(OCCU = ifelse(between(A, 3, 8) | between(B, 3, 8), "HOPD", "LOPD"))
```

The `between` function takes the value to be compared as its first parameter, the lower limit as its second parameter and the upper limit as its third parameter. Since it considers `<=`, I passed `8` rather than `9`.

Answer (score 0):

Let me help:

```
dataset <- data.frame(A = c(5,7,2,1),
                      B = c(9,2,1,9))

dataset$OCCU <- ifelse(dataset$A < 9 & dataset$A > 3 | 
                         dataset$B < 9 & dataset$B > 3, 
                       "HOPD", "LOPD")
```

This is the content of the dataset:

```
  A B OCCU
1 5 9 HOPD
2 7 2 HOPD
3 2 1 LOPD
4 1 9 LOPD
```